# Magento 2 - How to add dynamic-row multiselect?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3

[image]

This image what I already have. I have to make second column as multiselect. How to achieve this? This should be configuration field.

Comment: Can you add your code to your question what you have done?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html

Comment: This is for select and what you have done? I want to see your code what you have done yet.

Comment: My code the same at this time, except 2 rows... I have to do 2 columns - 1 select and 1 multiselect... I dont know how to achieve multiselect column, so i asked here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create Field class like below copied from magento dev docs

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\TaxColumn;

/**
 * Class Ranges
 */
class Ranges extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var TaxColumn
     */
    private $taxRenderer;

    /**
     * Prepare rendering the new field by adding all the needed columns
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('from_qty', ['label' => __('From'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('to_qty', ['label' => __('To'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('price', ['label' => __('Price'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('tax', [
            'label' => __('Tax'),
            'renderer' => $this->getTaxRenderer()
        ]);
        /* Multiselect code */
        $this->addColumn('country', [
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'renderer' => $this->getCountryRenderer(),
            'extra_params' => 'multiple="multiple"'
        ]);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare existing row data object
     *
     * @param DataObject $row
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row): void
    {
        $options = [];

        $tax = $row->getTax();
        if ($tax !== null) {
            $options['option_' . $this->getTaxRenderer()->calcOptionHash($tax)] = 'selected="selected"';
        }

        $countries = $row->getCountry();
        if(count($countries) > 0){
            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                $options['option_' . $this->getCountryRenderer()->calcOptionHash($country)]
                    = 'selected="selected"';
            }
        }

        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
    }

    /**
     * @return TaxColumn
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    private function getTaxRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->taxRenderer) {
            $this->taxRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                TaxColumn::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->taxRenderer;
    }

    /* Multiselect renderer for countries */
    private function getCountryRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->countryRenderer) {
            $this->countryRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\CountryColumn::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->countryRenderer;
    }
}
```

Create CountryColumn class under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/CountryColumn.php

with below content

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Braintree\Helper\Country;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select;

class CountryColumn extends Select
{
    private $countryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Country $countryHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->countryHelper = $countryHelper;
    }

    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value . '[]');
    }

    public function _toHtml(): string
    {
        if (!$this->getOptions()) {
            $this->setOptions($this->countryHelper->getCountries());
        }
        $this->setExtraParams('multiple="multiple"');
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, you are wizard, thank you very much!

Comment: good solution. (y)

Comment: I have implemented this, this is saving data to databse but not able to see it selected on load. Can you suggest me? [option_extra_attrs] => Array
        (
            [option_4200685455] => selected="selected"
        )
I get this extra in $row array. but not showing as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `$this->setExtraParams('multiple="multiple"');` is not enough
In your frontend_model, you need to set the option when there is array.

> protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row): void
> {
> $options = [];

```
    $region = $row->getRegion();


    if (is_array($region) && count($region) > 0) {
        foreach ($region as $r) {
            $options['option_' . $this->getRegionRender()->calcOptionHash($r)]
                = 'selected="selected"';
        }
    } else if ($region !== null) {
        $options['option_' . $this->getRegionRender()->calcOptionHash($region)] = 'selected="selected"';
    }




    $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
}
```

ANd in your column render, you need to set the html input name as array:

> public function setInputName($value)
> {
> return $this->setName($value . '[]');
> }